# Issue accessing drive from RAID array via USB caddy

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage, synology

I'm having a problem accessing the data from a drive that was in my NAS but is now plugged in via a USB caddy. This drive was not in a RAID array as it was a volume with a single disk. Although it seems the synology (DS414) NAS might have used SHR when it constructed the volume. The drive was removed to make way for a larger drive to expand another volume. Now I would like to retrieve the data from this drive, but it appears to not be accessible.

When plugged in via a caddy the old drive is not recognized, although it does show up with `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdq: 750.1 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/sdq1               1         311     2490240  fd Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/sdq2             311         572     2097152  fd Linux raid autodetect
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/sdq3             588       91201   727848912   f Win95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdq5             589       91189   727744480  fd Linux raid autodetect
```

I have tried using `mdadm -A --verbose --run /dev/md4 /dev/sdq5` then `mount /dev/md4 /mnt/usb` but I get a simple no such device response.

The command `cat /proc/mdstat` returns

```
md4 : active raid1 sdq5[0]
      727743296 blocks super 1.2 [1/1] [U]
```

I've tried `resize2fs` commands as well to try and fix possible faults with the filesystem. I've also tried using sdq3. But none of this works.

Does anyone know how I can access the data on this single drive?

Answer (score 0):

On thing that looks quite suspicious is the overlap of two partitions:

```
/dev/sdq3             588       91201   727848912   f Win95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdq5             589       91189   727744480  fd Linux raid autodetect
```

I assume you are wanting to access /dev/sdq5?  What is the /dev/sdq3 entry doing?

Try using fdisk -l -u=sectors for a more precise view of the partitions.

Finally, please show us the output of fsck.

Comment: fdisk -ul doesn't give any more information, the partitions appear to overlap. I assume its how SHR (Synology hybrid raid) works. I don't know which one would be best to access, but I've had no luck with either. Also I cannot install fsck as I'm accessing the drive through the synology box and its cut down linux (busybox) does not have a package manager.